# awk script to find the average of a particular row

Tags: shell, awk

Is it possible with awk to find a average of a certain row ?
For example the txt file (average.txt) contains:

```
2 5 10
1 5 5
1 5 10
```

So I want to find only first row average: 5,666667.

I tried to do it this way:
`awk 'NR==1 {sum+=NF} END {print(sum/NF)}' average.txt`
but the output is wrong: 1

Comment: Whatever solution you accept, change `print sum/NF` to `print (NF ? sum/NF : 0)` to protect against a divide by zero error when the target line is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to explain what your code is actually doing. `NF` built-in variable is holding number of files in current line thus for file average.txt

```
2 5 10
1 5 5
1 5 10
```

code

```
awk 'NR==1 {sum+=NF} END {print(sum/NF)}' average.txt
```

does for fist line increase sum by number of fields (3 for provided file) and then after processing all files does print that value divided by number of fields in last line, in other words your code does compute ratio of number of fields in 1st field and number of fields in last line. If you want to know more about `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i}END{print sum/NF}' file
5.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all fields and `sum` up all the values.

If you only want to process the first record, you can print the value directly and then exit awk.

To prevent a division by zero exception, you can check if the number of fields is > 0

```
awk 'NR==1 && NF>0 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print sum/NF; exit}' average.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution. It seems useless for me to loop on every line if only the first is the one you are interested in.

Instead, just `head -1` the file containing your data, like so (here, the file is called `test`):

```
head -1 test | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print sum/NF}'
```

Here, the awk command is basically copy/pasta from other answers, but without all the NR=1 stuff.